# Reciving more data than expected

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, rest

(This question has a spanish version: [Pregunta español StackOverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/348044/recibiendo-resultados-inesperados-e-incorrectos-springboot-hibernate))

Hello,

im creating a API-REST with springboot, hibernate ...
In one controller, im returning one entity, the point is, when i do this:

```
 Empresa company= empresaManager.findById(2L);
 return company;
```

returns exactly what i expect, (the object company has a list of students, and has only 2 vinculated).

But when instead of use a number, what i do is get the students, and afterwards, return the company of the students, the company that its returning me comes with 12 students (6 times repeated each student)

```
String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
token = token.replace("Bearer ", "");
Usuario usuario = tokenManager.getUsuarioFromToken(token);
Long id = usuario.getEmpresa().getIdempresa();
Empresa empresaOriginal = empresaManager.findById(id);
return empresaOriginal;
```

Any chance you know why is happenning this ?

This is how should return the object company:

[image]

And this is how im actually getting it:

[image]

### From here, to down, is what is asked in comments

This is my user entity :

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "usuario")
  public class Usuario {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "idusuario")
  private Long idusuario;

  @Column(name = "nombre", length = 30, nullable = false)
  private String nombre;

  @Column(name = "email", length = 80, nullable = false)
  private String email;

  @JsonIgnore
  @Column(name = "contraseña", length = 300, nullable = false)
  private String contraseña;

  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "empresa_idempresa"), name = "empresa_idempresa")
  private Empresa empresa;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Fichaje> fichajes;

  public Usuario() {
  }


  public Empresa getEmpresa() {
    return empresa;
  }


  public void setEmpresa(Empresa empresa) {
    this.empresa = empresa;
  }
}
```

This is my Company entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "empresa")
public class Empresa {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "idempresa")
  private Long idempresa;

  @Column(name = "nombre", length = 100, nullable = false)
  private String nombre;

  @Column(name = "contacto", length = 300, nullable = false)
  private String contacto;

  @Column(name = "fecha_inicio_practicas", columnDefinition = "DATE")
  private LocalDate inicioPracticas;

  @Column(name = "direccion", length = 100)
  private String direccion;

  @Column(name = "foto_empresa")
  private String fotoEmpresa;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<EmpresaTieneDia> empresaTieneDias;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Usuario> estudiantes;

  public Empresa() {
  }


  public Long getIdempresa() {
    return idempresa;
  }

  public void setIdempresa(Long idempresa) {
    this.idempresa = idempresa;
  }


  public List<Usuario> getEstudiantes() {
    return estudiantes;
  }

  public void setEstudiantes(List<Usuario> estudiantes) {
    this.estudiantes = estudiantes;
  }
}
```

This is the findById: 
(Service or Manager)

```
public Empresa findById(Long id) {
    return this.empresaRepository.findByIdempresa(id);
}
```

(Repository or DAO)

```
public interface EmpresaRepository extends CrudRepository<Empresa, Long> {
    Empresa findByIdempresa(Long id);
}
```

Comment: i know there i could do Empresa company = usuario.getCompany(). This anyway does th same problem giving 12 results unexpected

Comment: Can you please show your entites with the mapping and the code of findById

Comment: I just added it, tell me if you can help me with this headache. Thank you in advance

Comment: @mmomteirocl can you enable the show_sql property and check how many queries are getting executed in both the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

I had to change my listo of users from a `List<Usuario>` to a `Set<Usuario>`.

Anyways, I understand why it fixes it using a Set (cause doesn't let duplicated values in it). 
Anyways, if someone could try to explain my why in the first moment I'm having 6 times duplicated every item in the list i would apreciate it. 
Thanks !! :D